# "I think black and white matches/fits/fits in/suits better."

Tags: word-choice, verbs

If I want to say that I think that a photography looks better in black and white colours, can also use these words?

- I think black and white **suits** better.
- I think black and white **matches** better.
- I think black and white **fits** better.
- I think black and white **fits in** better.

I know theoretically how to use these kind of words in terms of clothes(because in my English lessons we were talking about these words describing clothes only), but I'm not sure how to use them talking for example about photographs.

Answer (score 2):

When I read your first sentence, I thought for a moment you were referring to black and white suits, and that you thought them better.

"Black and white" can be misread or misheard as a plural noun noun phrase.
You could avoid that saying "I think this photo would look better in black and white."

If you are already talking about photos and the option of using black and white, there's no possibility of confusion, and your suggested sentences could be used, but they would be clearer with a direct object for each of the verbs, for example:
"I think black and white suits the subject matter better."
"I think black and white fits the mood better."
"I think black and white matches the scene better."

Answer (score 1):

Added to Jack's contribution,  I suggest you also take a close look at your options.
 "fits in" may be regarded as tautology. Since  to fit already shows that it is into  something.